# How do I set a default prefix in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

A pretty simple question, but I couldn't find an example for it: 
How do I set a default prefix, as a naming rule (so that I get it underlined, if it's named differently), for specific **types** in ReSharper? Like "txt" for all `TextBox`s, "lbl" for all `Label`s and so on.

I found the C# Naming Style rules, but I couldn't figure out, how to add specific **types** to it. Could someone please give me a little example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible in currently (in R# 6.1) to set naming rules based on an object's **type**, which is what I think you want. In general, with .NET Microsoft has has turned away from [Hungarian Notation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), which is what `txtName` and so on are examples of.

Comment: Oh well, guess at least I am not blind then.